# clipped image not visible on Tablet EaselJS + sourceRect used

Tags: mobile, easeljs

i am working on a Mobile project (iPad with  iOS 8.0.2);
I want to make clipping of my immage in order to display less from it.
When displaying on PC it works perfectly well, while we test it on the tablet the clipped image is not displayed at all.
Do you have any suggestions

```
    this.background = new createjs.Bitmap('some_image.png');
    //create a clipping of drawn image!
    var dims = this.background.getBounds();
    this.background.sourceRect = new createjs.Rectangle(0, 15, dims.width, dims.height);
    this.background.x = 248;
    this.background.y = 86;
    this.stage.addChild(this.background);
```

Comment: Are you using phonegap? It seems that it doesn't work very well with preloadjs. Take a look at this: http://community.createjs.com/discussions/preloadjs/142-cant-load-files-in-phonegap-app

Comment: hi, renatop
I am neither using phonegap nor preloadjs

Comment: oh, are you waiting for the image to load completely before its use? If not, that's probably you problem.

Comment: yep, its loaded and its cached also
this happens only in iOS 8.0.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I met the same trouble like this.I have given up using Bitmap to clipping the image. I have found another solution ,here is "

[easeljs splitting an image into pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611522/easeljs-splitting-an-image-into-pieces/19619873#19619873)

".Good luck.

Comment: guys, please explain yourself when downvoting...
i would take this as a good roundaboutsolution nevermind that it is a roundup

Comment: i would take this as a good roundabout of the problem
sprites are drawn properly, bitmaps(non-croped) also
but to crop an image would be easier to use a "random" sprite
in answer provided is written about Bitmaps& sourceRects, but will not apply in our case

Answer (score -1):

I am working out, the code like this:

```
var img, stage;
function init() {
    //wait for the image to load
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = handleImageLoad;
    img.src = "./res/image.png";
}

function handleImageLoad(evt) {
    // create a new stage and point it at our canvas:
    stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

    // create a new Bitmap, and slice out one image from the sprite sheet:
    var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(evt.target).set({x:200, y:200});
    bmp.sourceRect = new createjs.Rectangle(916, 101, 84, 84); 
    //x,y,width,height

    stage.addChild(bmp);

    stage.update();
}
```

This is the example:
https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/Filters_animated.html